# Ion-item-option button needs to be clicked twice

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-item

I have an ion-list with sliding items in it and create these with a for loop.
You can click on the item itself and the router navigates to another page. When you slide an item, a button is revealed. and this Button needs to be clicked twice (at 90% of the time) to fire.

I already tried:

(click) in the `<ion-item>` and the `<ion-avatar>` tags. Same behaviour :(
I'm letting the user create an item and it's added to a list. this list ist stored in ionic storage with this.storage.set('list');
and the ion-list is created from this list above. so far so good this doesn't cause any problems.
and the number of list items doesn't affect the behaviour either.
the ion-list is in a `<div *ngIf = "loaded">` and loaded is set false later in `deleteHorse()` so this shouldn't affect anything.
when i click on the ion-item itself, it behaves correctly.
could it be that the item covers the ion-item-options and thus, the second click is realised as a click on the actual button and not the item?
I tried to add a hard coded item with sliding options - same thing...

and reported it to ionic on [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19564)

```
<div *ngIf="loaded">
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" routerDirection="forward">
      <ion-item-sliding #slidingItem (click)="dosomething()">
        <ion-item >
        <ion-avatar>
          <img [src]=items[0].imgUrl>
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{item[0].name}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="end">
          <ion-item-option (click)="showSureAlert(i, slidingItem)">
            <ion-button class="slideButton" >
              <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

```
async showSureAlert(index, item) {
    console.log('clicked');
    const text: any = [];
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: text.header = this.translateService.instant('delete'),
      message: text.message = this.translateService.instant('Warning.deleteHorse') + ' ' + this.horses[index][0].name + '?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: text.next = this.translateService.instant('no'),
          handler: () => {

          }
        },
        {
          text: text.next = this.translateService.instant('yes'),
          handler: () => {
            // delete horsename
            this.deleteHorse(index);
          }
        }
      ],
      backdropDismiss: false
    });
    console.log('alert created');
    await alert.present();
    item.close();
  }
```

The `console.log()` is also affected by this.

I would really like to use this but if there is no solution, I have to find another thing...
thanks in advance for your help.

**edit**

I copied the code from [ionicframework.com](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-sliding)
-> same result

And adapted my code to this example. 
Changing the position of the item-options (from end to start) made it a bit better(70% of the time it needs to be clicked twice)

have a look here: [example on github](https://github.com/Sunny41/example.git)

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] of your issue, so that we can see what you have tried, and tell you what's wrong (if any).

Comment: there is none. I tried to use just a simple ion-item sliding like the documentation on https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-sliding said. I copied the code and added a function "doSomething()" with just a console output in it. same result.

Comment: What I meant is that it's difficult to see your issue and know where it comes from without being able to play with it. So, if you could provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com reproducing it, I then could find what's causing the issue and offer a workaround to you.

Comment: ok :) stackblitz doesn't know what ion-item-option is... but i prepared a little project on github: https://github.com/Sunny41/example.git if you play a little with the sliding item option buttons, it will show the same behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an improvement. but this doesn't do its job reliable. The first 3-4 times it works with just one click. after that, I have to click twice.

and it looks ugly as hell :D

Buttons in an ion-item option are causing the problem. 
so at first I had:

```
 <ion-item-options side="end">
          <ion-item-option (click)="showSureAlert(i, slidingItem)">
            <ion-button class="slideButton" >
              <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>
```

and now:

```
<ion-item-options side="end">
          <ion-item-option (click)="showSureAlert(i, slidingItem)">
              <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          </ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>
```

still no solution, but better...

edit: 
at first with Ionic 4, there was this weird problem with ShadowDOM and i had to wrap my whole CSS file with  "host { }" to work correctly. 
i removed this and its working fine. silly thing.

Comment: basically i seen in your code you removed the ion-button  after that is it working perfectly or is there any better solution.

Comment: same behaviour, but a bit postponed. 3-5 times its working,  then fallback to double-click.